# My 3TB HD can't use 3TB? (only 2)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I have a Toshiba 3TB harddrive model HDKPC08. When I formated it using the windows 7 installer I saw a 2tb partition and another partition roughly 700 or 600gb. This appears to be a 3TB HDD. However I could NOT make it one (or two) big partition. The 700gb section I could not format. I got an error code. I installed windows 7 anyways and using disk manager I still can not format that section. What can I do? I tried looking for a firmware update but it doesn't appear Toshiba has any firmware downloads/installers/anything

What bothers me is I can see the unusable section in admin tools but I can't actually access it.

Comment: [Windows support for hard disks that are larger than 2 TB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2581408)

Comment: also have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Scalability

Comment: Is it MBR or GPT? Some drive manufacturers have a special driver to "split" drives larger than 2TB so that you can recognize the whole disk, but because it uses MBR, you can't have a drive larger than 2TB. You must use GPT

Comment: Windows 7 definitely does support GPT; however, the Windows *boot disk* can be GPT only if the firmware supports EFI/UEFI, and if the installer booted in that mode. Most computers sold since mid-2011 use EFI. If the disk is used as a data disk, it can be GPT even if Windows boots in BIOS mode.